# content url for local image file not working in Windows Phone 8 application

Tags: html, image, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

I had created a IBM Worklight project and its working fine for android and IOS, but with wp8 it's not working.

All the local image files are added to HTML DOM by using id in the image tag and providing url to content property, but for wp8 i have to provide inline src to call the images.

My question is how to call local images in the same way through external css file in windows phone?

I had tried calling the image from root folder but its not working i.e., content:url("www/default/images/abc.png");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 file path handling differs than other environments. Your path should be relative. You can look at the [multiple pages tutorial's](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/client-side-development-basics/building-multi-page-application/) sample project for special handling done for this purpose. Although you're done this in the HTML, so it's gonna be a bit of a problem...

By why not do this via CSS?
For example, if you have some DIV and you can want to give a background using an image that exists locally in the application's web resources, you can do this:

HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#test {
    background-image:url("../images/icon.png");
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I am not using background-image property content:url("../images/icon.png"); and its not working

Comment: Then provide your full implementation because we can't guess what you're doing there.

Comment: Hey Idan it seems content property is not supported in windows phone 8 app which am using for image, while background-image is working but it doesn't seems to be feasible for the app

Comment: Edit your question and explain what you're trying to do. Show an image of what it is, etc...

Comment: Hey Idan,What I am trying to explain to you is am using the below code for  creating a Hybrid app for android, ios and windows phone 8 .loginPasswordCheckImg ,.loginPasswordCheckBtnImg{
 content :url("../images/check_circle.png");
 background:#ffffff;
} now the code is working fine for android and ios as it can able to insert the image from content property but for windows phone 8 the area is blank, its unable to look for the image, I found that if I use background-image in place of content property its working, but using background-image property is not feasible throughtout the app

Comment: I understood that. But if you want better help then you need to provide what that you're doing. A sample app (not yours) that reproduces the issue so that we could then debug it.

Comment: its all about the css content property only

Comment: @Vice, I want to try and help, but I will only try doing so if you will provide a full sample project - HTML, CSS, JS. Can you or can you not, provide this?